# How do you search for content, not words?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp

Given a string that describes a situation or method, are there algorithms that create fingerprints out of it, compare it with a corpus to then point to pages where a similiar concept is being discussed?

The simple form is word search.

You search for word X and X appears in a text whose excerpt is shown to you.

This is the next step.

You describe X without writing "X" and you get text excerpts as a result where X is also described using different phrases (or even words) with or without an explicit mention of "X".

How do you search for content, not words?

Hint: I am looking for technical terms for this problem to find research papers.

Comment: More than 16 views and no reply? What is the real reason?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Just to answer your question: don't overthink it, there are  many questions and not that many contributors here. Hope you will join us ;)

Comment: Thanks Erwan, I will remember that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general principle about finding text based on meaning similarity is called [distributional semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributional_semantics). The main idea is that words with a similar meaning statistically tend to co-occur with the same context words. This is the basis for many standard tasks like [topic modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model), [word sense disambiguation/induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word-sense_disambiguation), and generally for everything related to semantics.

The problem you're describing is essentially [information retrieval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval): given a query expressed as one or several words, find the "documents" in a corpus which are semantically similar to this query.

[edit] Depending what the data looks like, you might be interested in the more specific task of [semantic textual similarity](https://nlpprogress.com/english/semantic_textual_similarity.html).

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question with "You describe X without writing "X" and you get text excerpts as a result where X is also described using different phrases (or even words) with or without an explicit mention of "X"." Does that change or extend your reply?

Comment: @PascalWidmann not really, the principle is the same: there are many variants of IR and many different methods, but they all rely on the same basic idea. A quite important technical difference is whether one relies on the traditional bag of word representation (where a word is a categorical variable) or the DL representation with word embeddings (a word is a vector obtained from training a DL model, and one can also have a document embedding etc.). I'm also adding another related link to my answer (textual similarity).

Comment: Are you aware of papers whose authors were able to search for ideas across different languages without a traditional translation step in between?

Comment: I researched a bit and figured that the term I am looking for is "Paraphrase-detection".

Comment: @PascalWidmann no I don't know semantic similarity across languages but it might exist. Normally this should be called a cross-lingual task (multilingual is usually for a task which can work with different languages independently, cross-lingual when the task works with several languages at once). Good that you found what you need!